# Jquery Checkbox That Checks List Below It

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-select2

I want to build a jquery function or onclick event which checks all checkbox if you click on the middle list and uncheck all checkbox above its list.

To explain futher, example I have 5 checkbox:

```
Checkbox 1
Checkbox 2
Checkbox 3
Checkbox 4
Checkbox 5
```

**First scenario:**

If I click Checkbox 3, all checkbox below will all be checked which is Checkbox 4 & Checkbox 5.

**Second scenario:**

If I uncheck Checkbox 3, all Checkbox 3,4 and 5 will be unchecked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the change event so that every time a checkbox changes its value you may set this new value (checked, unchecked) for the remaining elements:

```js
//
// When a checkbox changes its value do....
//

$(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
  //
  // get current value: checked/unchecked
  //
  var chk = this.checked;
  
  //
  // get all next checkbox elements and set their values
  // to the current value: checked/unchecked
  //
  // $(this).nextAll(':checkbox').prop('checked', chk);

   // UPDATE
  //
  // get all next checkbox elements and set their values
  // to the current value: checked/unchecked
  //
  if (chk == true) {
    $(this).nextAll(':checkbox').prop('checked', chk);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', chk);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="1">1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="2">2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="3">3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="4">4<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5">5<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this works pretty well. But is there way to disable all checked items (not included the unchecked ones) except the first checkbox that was check? I notice that you can still uncheck the middle and not all items above it are uncheck.

Comment: @KingDavid Sorry but I cannot understand what you are looking for. I updated my snippet: test it and let me know exactly (i.e.: with an example) what you are looking for. Thanks so much

Comment: Hi @gaetonoM. This now works pretty fine. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a list with all of your checkboxes with JS, and through a click event in any of them, you will iterate this list and check one by one, setting the property "checked = true;"

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Yes I understand but how will you iterate it using those scenario?

Comment: You could use the "each" method in Jquery, and use the value of the index to select the checkboxes that you want.

But, gaetanoM's answer is a better one! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Selecct All</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" id="1" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 1</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" id="2" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 2</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" id="3" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 3</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" id="4" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 4</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" id="5" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 5</li>
    <li><input class="checkbox" id="6" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

//$(this).attr('id') get current id 
//$(":checkbox").length get all checkbox

```
 $('.checkbox').change(function(){ //".checkbox" change

       for(int i=$(this).attr('id');i<= $(":checkbox").length;i++)
       {
           if(this.checked == false){
              $("#" + i).prop('checked', true);
           }
           else{
              $("#" + i).prop('checked', false);
           }
       }  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also want to share my answer. This is an update and modifications from answers above:

```
 function fncSubCheck() {
//Use this instead of document.ready to make sure it will run when needed
        $(document).off('click', '.obj-check');
        $(document).on('click', '.obj-check', function (e) {
//Check if checkbox is check and check all items below it
            var blIsCheck = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (blIsCheck) {
                var objNext = $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find('.obj-check');
                $(objNext).prop('checked', blIsCheck);
            } else {
//Will uncheck all items above it
                var objPrev = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll().find('.obj-check');
                $(objPrev).prop('checked', blIsCheck);
            }
        });
    }
```